# SUM(IF()) not working

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to calculate the sum of a column but only if the value of another column on that row has a certain value:

```
---------
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 5 |
---------
```

This should yield: A=3 and B=5.

After some attempts, I copied the following from [their website](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays#Tips_and_Tricks)

```
=SUM((C3:C5="red")*(B3:B5="big")*D3:D5)
```

Which doesn't work: whatever I try, I always seem to get `#VALUE!`... Any workarounds to accomplish this?

This is LibreOffice: 4.4.2.2.
+ I've checked the formatting of the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a task, you don't need an array formula - it's a typical task for a pivot table. To use it:

1. Add Column headers:

   [image]
2. Select the "data table" (in my example: `A1:B4`);
3. Menu `Data` -> `Pivot Table` -> `Create...`; confirm current selection as source:

   [image]
4. Drag <kbd>Category</kbd> to column (or row) fields, and <kbd>Count</kbd> to Data fields. LO offers to sum the count, you can select other functions to apply on the data fields:

   [image]
5. Optionally, open more options, select "identify categories";
6. Hit ok:

   [image]